# comment form in drupal views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-comments

I want to add separate comment form for each node showed in a view.
I used template row using following code:

```
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = strip_tags($fields['nid']->content);
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
print render($form);
```

Form is showed, but doesnt work properly. When I click on save, instead of saving the comment it redirect me to following url:
comment/reply/35 (in case I try to add a comment for node 35)

Regards

Comment: Well, that is how its saved and you are get redirected to newly saved comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using hook_form_alter, you may change $form['#action'] and edit the action form to your custom url.

This [post](https://drupal.org/comment/7686765#comment-7686765) can be helpful to change the destination url after submitting the comment.